# Фильтрация знаков препинания на PHP не совсем правильно работает

Tags: php, фильтрация

Код :

```
$words = preg_replace("|[^\d\w ]+|i","",$words);
```

Проблема в том что он убирает НЕ ТОЛЬКО ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ , а и КИРИЛЛИЦУ!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте это. работает

```
$words = preg_replace("|[^\d\wа-яА-Я ]+|i","",$words);
```

Comment: реально РАБОТАЕТ1!!! СПАСИБО!!!

Answer (score 1):

Либо используйте модификатор `u` и передавайте входную строку в UTF-8,

```
$words = preg_replace("|[^\d\w ]|iu","",$words);
```

либо ищите именно *знаки препинания* и удаляйте их

```
$words = preg_replace("|[,.:;]+|","",$words);
```

либо перечислите в шаблоне и кирилицу

```
$words = preg_replace("|[^\d\wа-я ]|i","",$words);
```

Comment: спасибо вам тоже